# XPCOM Shockwave Flash C++

Tags: c++, flash, firefox, xpcom

I recently started "playing" with xpcom, and I would like to know if there is a way
do interact with a Shockwave flash element.

In IE I can use the IShockwaveFlash interface, but for the Firefox I can't find any interface.

I tried using the nsIFlash5 definition from the header file "wrap_XPCOM_3rdparty.h" (acquired from the XulRunner-1.9 source code [link](http://xulrunner-1.9.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.9.0.2plus-pbuild3plus-pnobinonly/wrap__XPCOM__3rdparty_8h-source.html) ) and I can sucessfuly query a 
nsIDOMHTMLEmbedElement for the nsIFlash5 interface, but I'm unable to use any of the functions, since it "crashes".

Thanks.